# How to distinguish Alt and ISO_Level3_Shift in xkb?

Tags: keyboard, xkb, alt

I am using a device with a builtin keyboard and run ARM Debian on it with i3 as Window Manager. There is one `Alt` key (keysym `Alt_L`), and two keys for special characters that look similar to `AltGr` since they correspond to `ISO_Level3_Shift` according to `xev`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x38c, subw 0x0, time 86851282, (270,736), root:(1903,793),
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x38c, subw 0x0, time 86851413, (270,736), root:(1903,793),
    state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x38c, subw 0x0, time 86854252, (270,736), root:(1903,793),
    state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x38c, subw 0x0, time 86854362, (270,736), root:(1903,793),
    state 0x8, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Yet, despite different keysyms, all three keys are considered the same by Debian and i3 WM: regardless of the key I press, they all serve as the modifier key in i3 after I set `$mod` to `Mod1` in my i3 config. I haven't found a way too make my system distinguish them.

Is there a way to separate the two keysims and keep `Alt` base function, i.e., make it open menus in GUI applications but not trigger i3 modifier? Or, alternatively, my preference would be to use `Alt_L` to reach third-level xkb symbols, and `ISO_Level3_Shift` as my i3 modifier; how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the `setxkbmap` options that allowed me to assign the correct function to each keys in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jatcwang/ae3b7019f219b8cdc6798329108c9aee).

So adding this in my i3 `config` worked to set the `Alt` key to `ISO_Level3_Shift` and my other modifier key (duplicated on both sides of the keyboard) to `Super_R`:

```
exec --no-startup-id setxkbmap -model fxtecpro1 -layout fxtec_vndr/pro1 -variant us2 -rules evdev -option lv3:lalt_switch, compose:caps, altwin:swap_alt_win
```

There are some other unrelated options in the command, either for personal taste or to comply with the peculiarities of my device. `pro1` is a `xkb` file tailed to the device, and `us2` is a custom `us-intl` variant.

However, despite the change, i3 still ignores the difference between the keys and they still all act as `$mod` when I set i3 to use `Mod1`. I believe this is because I use Xwayland, and even if `xmodmap` and `xev` report the correct settings, `Xwayland` probably does not take them into account. I guess `Wayland` alternatives would work for `Xwayland`, but I don't think I can have this level of customization using `Wayland` alternatives.